# Unity Photon timer synchronization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, multiplayer, photon

Im using Unity Photon for teamplay multiplayer game.

I have 2 teams A and B. There is also a zone on the map, if you get into it (only to one team), then the timer decreases from 10 seconds and when the value is 0, a certain action occurs. This zone works through OnTriggerStay. I have difficulties with this: When one player enters this zone, then everything is ok, the timer tends from 10 seconds to 0 at normal speed, BUT, when another player from the same team comes in, then the timer **passes twice** as fast. I need a **normal** multiplayer countdown timer, for this zone, not the x2 multi-seconds.

```
private double _timeToNewScore = 10f;
private double _time;
private bool hasCapturedOne

private List <Health> team1players;

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{ 
 if (hasCapturedOne) 
 { 
   foreach (Health p in team1players) 
    { 
     ScorePointsFromPeriod(1); 
    }
 }
}

 private void ScorePointsFromPeriod(int team)
 {
         _time += Time.deltaTime; 
         if (_time >= _timeToNewScore)
         {
             DoSomething();
         }
 }
```

Please, help me to avoid multiply seconds in timer, if there 2 teammates in zone. thx

Comment: Hi, Thank you for choosing Photon! Did you consider making use of `PhotonNetwork.Time` which is the same across clients?

Comment: @JohnTube, yes,will do, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do this would be have some `int` that stores how many players are in your area, and check if there is *at least one* player there (you can use `OnTriggerEnter()` and `OnTriggerExit()` to increment/decrement your count.
Then in an `Update()` method, decrease your timer if the number of players in your area is greater than 0